# How to stub SOAP client request with sinon in Node JS?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, soap, sinon, strong-soap

I am using `strong-soap` module to get data from SOAP request.

```
var soap = require('strong-soap').soap;

soap.createClient(url, options, function (err, client) {
     var method = client.GetInfoSOAP;
     method(requestQuery, function (err, info) {
      // bla bla
     }
}
```

I am getting the required data. Now
I want to write unit test case to mock the SOAP request using `sinon` stub, but didn't get any success. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: did my answer help you?

Answer (score 0):

What you want is controlling the `soap` object's `createClient`. You can do that using techniques that fall into one of two categories:

1. Dependency injection - expose a setter through which you can inject a fake module you control yourself for testing
2. Using link seams - hook into the import/require mechanism and override what the module is getting.

The Sinon project has [a nice page](http://sinonjs.org/how-to/link-seams-commonjs/) on using link seams through `proxyquire`, and I have also detailed [how to do DI on the issue tracker](https://github.com/sinonjs/sinon/issues/831#issuecomment-198081263).

To achieve the first, all you need is to do something like this in the module:

```
module.exports._injectSoap = (fake) => soap = fake;
```

Then in your test code:

```
const fakeSoap = { createClient : sinon.stub().returns(/* ? */) }
myModule._injectSoap(fakeSoap);

...
assert(fakeSoap.createClient.calledOnce);
assert(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi i have solved my problem with the following code :

```
sinon.stub(soap, 'createClient').yields(null, {
        GetInfoSOAP: function (request, cb) {
            return cb(null, myDesiredData);
        }
    });
```